# How to create batch file to remove double quotes from particular column from csv file

Tags: batch-file

How to create batch file to remove double quotes from particular column from csv file

Input csv file:

```
"DocumentType","Company","Division","SeasonYear","Style"
"832","XYZ","S17","2017","S"
"832","XYZ","S17","2017","M"
```

I want to remove double quotes from column 1 where values will be DocumentType in header (first record) and 832 for remaining records.

Expected result should be:

```
DocumentType,"Company","Division","SeasonYear","Style"
832,"XYZ","S17","2017","S"
832,"XYZ","S17","2017","M"
```

I tried with below batch script but it replaces all double quotes in file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set FileIn=out.csv
set FileOut=in2.csv

(
    for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%FileIn%") do (
    set Line=%%A
    set Line=!Line:"=!
    for /L %%B in (1,1,20) do (
        set Line=!Line: ,=,!
        set Line=!Line:, =,!
    )
    echo.!Line!
    )
 ) > "%FileOut%"
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q46039339.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=," %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO ECHO %%~a,%%b
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q46039339.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Read each line of the input file, assigning the part before the first `,` to `%%a` and the remainder to `%%b`

Use the `~` operator to remove the quotes from `%%a`, add back the commad and regurgitate the remainder of the line.

The parentheses surrounding the `for` statement allow the `echo`es to be redirected to a new file as defined.

Answer (score 3):

Single line batch file solution:

```bat
@(For /F Tokens^=1*Delims^=^" %%A In (input.csv) Do @Echo %%A%%B)>output.csv
```

*Change the input and output .csv file names as necessary.*

Comment: This for help

This works for first record. But I want to repeat this for all the lines in input file

Comment: As you now have working solutions, I would advise you decide which you prefer as a solution and mark it as your accepted answer.

Comment: Simpler: `(for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %a in (input.csv) do @echo %~a,%b) > output.csv` (from the command line)

Comment: @Aacini, that was what Magoo had already used, _hence my alternative_, though I do not see how it's any simpler, _the only difference being the choice of delimiter_.

Comment: You are right! I didn't carefully reviewed Magoo's answer... **`:(`** This method is simpler because it don't require to escape the special characters that may confuse many Batch-file users.

Answer (score 0):

This is batch code which worked perfectly for my requirement. First read all csv file and replaced where "DocumentType"= DocumentType and "832"=832

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

copy 832*.csv 832_tmp.csv
set FileIn=832_tmp.csv
set FileOut=832.csv

(
  for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%FileIn%") do (
  set Line=%%A
                    REM replace "DocumentType" to DocumentType and "832" to 832
  set Line=!Line:"DocumentType"=DocumentType!
  set Line=!Line:"832"=832!

  echo.!Line!
)  > 832.csv            REM wtite output file 
)
del 832_tmp.csv         REM delete temporary created file
```